# Boot computer on bringing it to power

Tags: boot, bios, power-management

I'm trying to reach following:
I have a multi master/slave power point. My computer is plugged in into the master slot.

The whole multi power point is plugged in into a radio power point I can control with a remote (power on / off).

I turned on the "Restore on AC Power Loss"-option in my computer's BIOS.

So, when I feed my radio power button with electricity by turning it on with the remote, my computer should boot without pressing it's power button.

But the problem is: It doesn't boot. I also tried removing the whole remote and master/slave things. I only activated the BIOS option and plugged the computer directly to the power point in my wall - no difference. It doesn't boot on plugging in the cable.

What am I doing wrong? What could I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The option, which you mention "Restore on AC Power Loss" is for when the PC loses AC power (i.e. during a power outage) what will happen once the power is restored.

So this might not apply to your scenario. Some PC's (specifically, I've seen this option on some laptops) have the option to power on when connected to AC power. This is the option you should be looking for, but depending on your PC / Motherboard model. You may not have this option available in BIOS.

Comment: I have these options: ACPI Suspend Mode, Deep Power Off Mode,  Power On by RTC Alarm, Power On by PCIE Devices, Power On by PCI Devices, Wake Up by PS/2 KB/Mouse, Wake Up by USB KB/Mouse, Restore On AC Power Loss... I tried all function enabled and disabled, but with no success. Is there another way to reach what I want?

Comment: Yes, I don't think your computer will do what you want, just from supplying it power. You probably need to look into one of the other "wake up" options you listed: *"Power On by RTC Alarm, Power On by PCIE Devices, Power On by PCI Devices, Wake Up by PS/2 KB/Mouse, Wake Up by USB KB/Mouse"*

Comment: That's sad :( Well, I wanted to get some new components for my computer anyway. Seems that the motherboard will be one of those.